# Crossbrowser position:fixed but still fails?

Tags: javascript, css, position, css-position

The following example of making a `position : fixed` does not work in my FF16.02 / IE9. But as far as I known, it should be crossbrowser compatible.
Any Ideas?

[JSfiddle of the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/rcMe9/)

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? `position:fixed` generally works really well cross-browser, so either you want it to do something different than what it is intended for or your implementation is not correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem lies in `document.body.scrollTop`. That is not cross-browser compatible. Use `window.scrollY`, and it should work perfectly fine.

Your code would change to this:

```
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');
document.onscroll = function(e) {
    if (window.scrollY > foo.offsetTop) {
        foo.className = "foo sticky";
    } else {
        if (foo.className.indexOf('sticky')) {
            foo.className = "foo";
        }
    }
};​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rcMe9/1/)

Answer (score 0):

[Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/rcMe9/3/)   open this i updated 
you have to set 
`position:fixed` in foo div too

i think this is the solution